# value of setenv doesn't loaded by helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I create the `yaml` files for kubernetes i can deploy without any problem . my application is running perfectly .
However  when i translate it in `helm` i 've a problem :(

what i did is after running the application with yaml files in K8s  and helm i run the command below

`kubectl get deployment --namespace ds-svc-cas -o yaml`

and i can see with helm it doesn't load the `value` params of env  and i dont understand why ??

**from k8s :**

```
 template:
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: ds-cas
      env: beta
  spec:
    containers:
    - env:
      - name: JAVA_APP_CONFIGS
        value: /apps/ds-cas-webapp/context
      - name: JAVA_EXTRA_PARAMS
        value: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./config/jaas.config -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=6402
      image: docker-all.attanea.net/library/ds-mg-cas:latest
```

**for helm :**

```
  template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: ds-cas
      spec:
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: JAVA_APP_CONFIGS
          - name: JAVA_EXTRA_PARAMS
          image: docker-all.attanea.net/library/ds-mg-cas:latest
```

the **config files of k8s & and helm **

https://gist.github.com/zyriuse75/7ca729367ab7c8852a0293e1c59447e6

Comment: can we see the helm template?

Comment: you have it on the gist the first file ** deployment-helm.yaml **

Comment: I've tested helm with these files and everything seems to be ok, it renders correctly the vars {{ .Values.setEnv.conf }} and {{ .Values.setEnv.params }}, are you sure there were no syntax errors? how do you deploy it?

Comment: i 'm sure there is no syntaxe error . but why when i run the command  `... -o yaml ` after deployed with helm i dont see the value of var below name ? normally i've to see it right ??

Comment: the solution was to write`value` without `s` . i wrote `values : xxx`